# Basic macro on excel 2016 mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I use a basic macro on office 2016 but when I try to run it on mac nothing happens.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).NumberFormat = "0"
    End Sub
```

My fisrt objective is to update all the pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

If your excel calculations is not manual mode i.e. Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual then **ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll** might not work !

Try this,

```
Sub RefreshPivots()
    Dim pivot As PivotTable
    For Each pivot In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        pivot.RefreshTable
    Next pivot
End Sub
```

Comment: ` Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    RefreshPivots()
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).NumberFormat = "0"
  End Sub
Sub RefreshPivots()
    Dim pivot As PivotTable
    For Each pivot In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        pivot.RefreshTable
    Next pivot
End Sub
`


So i have to do that ?